# Create metallic material using script

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I want to create a metallic look for a sphere which will be used as part of an animation. I tried to use the Glossy BSDF and Anisotropic BSDF surfaces but still wasn't able to achieve desired results. I want the sphere to look as it looks in the preview window, but also using 3 area lights system didn't do the trick for me.
I'm using Blender 2.8 and I want to create this material using script.

This is the current layout and shading:

[image]
[image]

Example of the desired result (found on the web):

[image]

Thank you all :)

Comment: What exactly is the difference you are looking for?
Is your upper render Eevee? If so use screen space reflections.

Comment: The title and tags mention scripting, but nothing in your question does. Are you trying to do this with Python?